# Получение разницы во времени

Tags: gwt, javascript, java

Как получить разницу во времени, те имеется некий объект Data, который надо сравнить с текущим временем. Делаю так:

```
Date today = new Date();
Date somePastData = a.getData();
Date diff = new Date(today.getTime()-somePastData .getTime());
```

Вывожу примерно так:

```
String dateDiff = diff.getHours() + ":" + diff.getMinutes() + ":" + diff.getSeconds();
```

Для теста

```
somePastData = new Date();
```

Проблема в том, что на разных машинах отображается разное время. Те где-то 3:0:1, а где-то 18:0:5. Получается, что в минутах  и секундах все ок, а в часах ошибка. Где может быть ошибка?

Важно: Библиотека **GWT**!

Answer (score 1):

1. Решение задачи изначально неверно. Экземпляр Date в общем случае не может представлять разницу во времени между двумя датами.
2. Формат отображения даты зависит от локали, соответственно нужно либо следить за одинаковостью локалей, либо использовать собственный форматер (см. java.text.DateFormat).

Answer (score 1):

В дополнение к ответу a_gura. Вы можете искать разницу в датах через разницу представлений дат в миллисекундах (метод `Date#getTime()`) и вручную вычислять оттуда часы, минуты и все остальное.

UPD. А еще в Apache Commons Lang уже есть (что неудивительно) то, что вам нужно - [DurationFormatUtils](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang/time/DurationFormatUtils.html).

Answer (score 1):

Также есть замечательная библиотека [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/), которая позволяет выполнять множество манипуляций с датами.

Answer (score 0):

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat ("hh:mm:ss" );
String result = format.format ( diff );
```